# How to generate Styled text for TextView while assembling string?

Tags: android, coding-style, textview

I have a TextView that will hold a styled, multiline string.  This text is generated line by line as the data is drawn from different sources bit by bit.  As I grab each field, I add a Bold header to the TextView on a new line, then I add the data for that field in italics on a new line.

Example formatting:

**Due Date**
*July 22, 2010*
**Course**
*CSC 350*

I could set the styling like this:

```
Spannable str = (Spannable) textview.getText();

str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.Bold), 0, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.Italic), 8, 21, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.Bold), 21, 27, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.Italic), 27, 33, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But that requires knowing the length of each section of text at runtime which is simply unmanageable since there is a variable number of data fields that could be added to the textview.

How can I add the styling as I'm adding each piece of text instead of after all the text has been added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark your string up with `<b>` and `<i>` tags as appropriate and then use the [Html.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to return the Spannable you are looking for.

Comment: If you're getting the styled string from a resource, this other answer will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml

Answer (score 3):

`Html.fromHtml(String)` carries a lot more baggage with it than the more light weight `SpannableString` classes. Whenever possible I would recommend that you avoid `fromHtml` to style a string.

In your case you could build the string with `SpannableStringBuilder` and then set the `TextView` text with the final styled string.

```
// set the text
SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString("Due Date\n");
SpannableString s2 = new SpannableString("July 22, 2010\n");
SpannableString s3 = new SpannableString("Course\n");
SpannableString s4 = new SpannableString("CSC 350\n");

// set the style
s1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s2.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, s2.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s3.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, s3.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s4.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, s4.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// build the string
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(s1);
builder.append(s2);
builder.append(s3);
builder.append(s4);

// set the text view with the styled text
textView.setText(builder);
```

I set the text and styles one by one but in real usage this could easily be done in a loop. Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Comment: That styles the whole textview, not spans of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `Spannable` as the text of the `TextView`. That way you can create your text first, add style info when needed, and put that into the `TextView` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how [HTML](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) class does it. I would parse the input and generate the spannable on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is somewhat old but as it is the top on google, I'd like to throw in the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) as a good resource for this. The bottom contains suggestions for helper methods to style your text programatically.