# Insert Java code in a TextView

Tags: java, android, html

How to show Java code in a TextView?

[image]

Comment: Most likely, that is using a `WebView` and one of the many syntax-highlighting libraries, not `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store your code as HTML and parse HTML using [HTML.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to show styled HTML in your `TextView`. for more information, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233657/how-to-generate-styled-text-for-textview-while-assembling-string)

Comment: when i do this , the code appear like this in the format 
http://prntscr.com/g5h8mq